# How to force delayed execution of an expression or property accessor in F# without using an extra keyword like "lazy"

Tags: lambda, f#

I was experimenting with the following before realizing that arguments on either side of an operator are always evaluated *prior* to passing them through:

```
let tryGet f =
    try
        f() |> sprintf "%A"
    with
    | e -> sprintf "ERROR: %s" e.Message
let (!%) a = tryGet(fun() -> a)
sprintf "Test: %A" !% this.Property
```

It looks as if `!% this.Property` would expand to `tryGet(fun() -> this.Property)`, but this is not true, it is closer to:

```
let a = this.Property
tryGet(fun() -> a)
```

Now I know that I can use `lazy` to force lazy evaluation, but I was wondering if with standard syntax (meaning: without `lazy` itself, or `let!` for that matter), or perhaps with the new way of auto-quotations of F# 4.4, one can create a lazily-evaluated expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

F# has applicative order of evaluation, which means that function arguments get fully evaluated before the function is applied, and this applies to any function, including prefix operators.

So the only way to defer expression evaluation is to hide it in a closure, which you quite understandably don't want to do.

One "hack" that the compiler provides is the `lazy` keyword, and frankly, I don't understand why you don't like it, because it can't get any shorter than this - only add one keyword:

```
let deferred = lazy f()
let evaluated = deferred.Value
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought to have understood. The other hack being `let!` and `do!` and friends, which wrap your expression in a bind expression, which will delay execution as well. Yes, `lazy` is what we use all over the place when lazy evaluation is needed. Aren't auto-quotations also a possibility? Though they don't apply to functions, they could be used for an (expensive, I assume) way of implementing lazy evals for methods.

Comment: Using auto-quotation would be more heavy syntax than `lazy`.

Comment: Understandably so. So, if we try to be complete, we have `lazy` which lazily evaluates any expression, we have `fun` of course which will create a lambda that's only evaluated when called, and we have (auto-)quotations. And none of those allow being "replaced" by operators or functions because of "applicative order of evaluation", is that correct, did I forget anything?

Comment: About right. You forgot to mention computation builders, but those can be viewed as syntactic sugar for building closures, but then so can `lazy`. So at the lowest level, one might say there are just two mechanisms - closures and quotations.

Answer (score 0):

*(adding this as an addition to the correct answer from Fyodor)*

### Alternative method 1

Just realized that when the requirement is to lazily load properties, there's another, much simpler approach. Just get the gettor member function.

In other words, from my OP, change this:

```
let (!%) a = tryGet(fun() -> a)
sprintf "Test: %A" !% this.Property
```

Into this:

```
let (!%) prop = tryGet(prop())
sprintf "Test: %A" !% this.get_Property    // note the "get_" prefix
```

This works, even though by default the property gettor method is hidden (and in C# of VB it is not even directly accessible), it is available in F# and can be passed around just like any other function.

This has the added advantage that if the object is `null`, it will not throw on the call-site, but only inside the `tryGet` wrapper function.

### Alternative method 2

F# comes with the `?` operator, which takes its left-hand operand as normal, and its right-hand operand as a stringized value of whatever you put there.

Its intend is to allow dynamic programming in F#, but you'll have to create the necessary reflection yourself.

Of course, this is much slower than a normal closure, but it is also more flexible and it certainly is a way of delayed execution of the object accessors.